# mysql db structure

Tags: mysql, database

I have this school management project. 
the issue is each year i have to manually create a new db to hold all students, teachers records(profiles and grades).
Now im thinking of creating a central db that will hold all data that do not change over the year, then each year should have a db that holds student yearly records. 
it this a good  db structural idea?

Comment: Could you show us some examples of what your tables look like currently?

Comment: @Daan, thanks for the responses. the db is very large i wish i can attach a snap shoot of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would not create an entirely new DB for yearly records at all. Without knowing the actual data you need to store (the more details on this you can provide, the better), generically I would set up a single DB to house all data (static *and* dynamic), and use the records themselves to differentiate the years/classes/students/teachers. Such as:

```
table `teachers`
----------------
id
first name
last name
email
phone
...


table `students`
----------------
id
first name
last name
year
email
...


table `classes`
---------------
class_id
class_name
class_description
....


table `teacher_classes`
-----------------------
year
class_id
teacher_id
...


table `student_classes`
-----------------------
year
class_id
student_id
grade
...
```

And so forth. Then you don't have to create new tables/DBs each year; you just input new records in the proper tables and relate them.

Comment: thanks for the response, i think i will try this option, but my issue is the number of records in the student_classes will be much

Comment: @kabiridris Define "much." Your DB should be able to handle it easily when structured properly.